# De-reference in if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, iterator, dereference

In the first statement, `it` is de-referenced to 0, because element 1 in the vector is 0. In my second if-statement, I would like to increment `it` before de-referencing it.

```
int function(vector<int>& vec){
    for (auto it = vec.begin() + 1; it != vec.end(); ++it){
        if (*it == 0)
        {
            cout << "element 1 = 0" << endl;
            if (*(it +1) && *(it +2) == 0)
                cout << "element 2 and 3 = 0";
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    vector<int>grid = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2 };
    function(grid);
```

Output:

> element 1 = 0

Goal Output:

```
element 1 = 0
element 2 and 3 = 0
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check that both elements are equal to zero, you need to use:

```
if (*(it +1) == 0 && *(it +2) == 0)
```

instead of:

```
if (*(it +1) && *(it +2) == 0)
```

There is no problem with incrementing or dereferencing the iterators, because `vector`'s iterators are random-access, which allows incrementing them with `it + n`.

There is also a problem in your code that incrementing the iterators could go past the last element, which would cause undefined behavior.